How to access byte representation of float by casting to char * in C?
I am learning C, and partly to get used to pointers and partly to learn about IEEE 754 floats, I tried the following:
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    float f1 = -12.78;
    const char *p =  (char *)&f1;
    for(int i=0; i < sizeof(f1); i++) {
        printf("i: %i and p: %p and byte is %#x\n",i,p,*p);
        p++;
    }
}

I don't get any warnings or errors (unlike most of the versions I tried before!), but I do get strange results:
i: 0 and p: 0x16ce13368 and byte is 0xffffffe1
i: 1 and p: 0x16ce13369 and byte is 0x7a
i: 2 and p: 0x16ce1336a and byte is 0x4c
i: 3 and p: 0x16ce1336b and byte is 0xffffffc1

My (limited) understanding of IEEE 754 is that -12.78 is indeed e1 7a 4c c1 in bytes, but why is the first byte shown as ff ff ff e1 (and similarly for the last byte)?
Is there a better way to do this?
I also tried using char arrays, but didn't get very far with that. I also tried using a void *p to access the memory holding the float, but couldn't get that to work either.

Use an unsigned type to avoid sign extension for negative numbers.

Don't treat it as a character pointer, but as an integer. You can then extract the parts of the number by bit shifting, From the left you have sign (1 bit), biased exponent (8 bits) and mantissa (23 bits).

Changing the two instances of char to unsigned char fixed the problem. Thank you. Is this in general a good way to 'inspect' the bytes of arbitrary structures and types? Also, is there a way to do this using an unsigned char[] rather than a pointer? (Or is that a dumb idea?)

On your C implementation, char is an 8-bit signed integer type, so any byte values in the range 0x80 to 0xff will be treated as small, negative integers in the range -128 to -1. By the default argument promotions of the variable arguments of printf, those 8-bit char values will be sign-extended to int values (which are 32-bit on your C implementation). The %#x printf specifier will treat those int values as unsigned int.

Ah. That explains it. I do now vaguely remember reading in the docs for printf about promotion to unsigned int before display. Thanks

Here you go

When dereferencing a pointer, you are not restricted to accessing the object directly at the pointer location. You can use pointer arithmetic or array indexing to access nearby objects. For example, instead of incrementing p in the loop, you could replace *p in the printf argument with *(p + i) or p[i] to access the byte at offset i from the pointer. (There are restrictions, you cannot access beyond the bounds of the object or array.)

Thank you Ian Abbott. That is exactly what I was trying to figure out (but hadn't got to work in my experimentation)

@OldBoy: "Treating it as an integer" is difficult to do without violating the strict aliasing rule.  Character types have an exemption from that rule.

The way to get around the strict aliasing rule is to use memcpy() to copy the bytes to an integer. And either way, you have to ensure that you're using a large enough integer type.

@NateEldredge I don't really think the strict aliasing rule is relevant in such a piece of code.

@OldBoy: If p were an int *, as you suggested in your previous comment, then the strict aliasing rule would be violated, which would invoke undefined behavior.

Note that when formatting char-sized numbers, it is appropriate to use the corresponding width modifier, hh.  In this case, that would be %#hhx.  You should also match signedness: %x, %u, and %o  expect values of unsigned type, whereas %d and %i expect values of signed type. In practice, it sometimes works to get just one of those attributes correct, especially for output, but you should not rely on that.

That is good to know. Is there a good cheat sheet for printf? (I've found a few, but didn't find them that great.) I thought the table in the standard documentation would be enough, but I missed things like the above (especially the length modifiers).

@AndreasWenzel That is not what I suggested. My suggestion was to treat the float variable as an integer with a simple cast, oin order to access the three sets of bits.

As char is signed and promoted to int when used in the printf. That is the reason you see those negative int numbers printed as hex.
Use unsigned type and the correct format
int main() {

    float f1 = -12.78;
    const unsigned char *p =  (const unsigned char *)&f1;
    for(int i=0; i < sizeof(f1); i++) {
        printf("i: %i and p: %p and byte is %hhx\n", i, (void *)p,*p);
        p++;
    }
}


char is signed on the OP's particular compiler and flags. On other setups, it can be unsigned, because char, rather uniquely, has implementation-defined signedness, and is distinct from both signed char and unsigned char.

@ShadowRanger unsigned char will always work. char not.

I agree that unsigned char works. I'm saying your first sentence can be read to imply char is always signed, when that is not the case.
